# ASP .NET Core Controller on Api Call not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can somebody help me out. I'm trying to get a API Call from Angular Frontend to ASP .Net Core Backend. Here is my code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly OrderManagmentContext _context;

    public CustomerController(OrderManagmentContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost("saveCustomer")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CustomerDto>> saveCustomer(CustomerDto customer)
    {
        var entity = new Customer
        {
            Name = customer.Name,
            LastName = customer.LastName,
            City = customer.City,
            Company = customer.Company,
            EMail = customer.EMail,
            Id = customer.Id,
            Phone = customer.Phone,
            PostalCode = customer.PostalCode,
            Street = customer.Street,
        };
        _context.Customers.Add(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return customer;

    }

}
```

CustomerService and SaveButton:

```
saveCustomer(customer: CustomerDto) {
const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
const body = JSON.stringify(customer);
return this.http.post<CustomerDto>(this.baseUrl + 'api/customer/savecustomer', body, { headers });}

async addCustomer() {
const dto = {} as CustomerDto;
Object.assign(dto, this.formGroup.value);
await firstValueFrom(this.customerService.saveCustomer(dto));  }
```

Here is my error: (in WEB)

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not
> Found","url":"https://localhost:44405/api/customer/savecustomer","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http
> failure response for
> https://localhost:44405/api/customer/savecustomer: 404 Not
> Found","error":"\n<html lang="en">\n\n<meta
> charset="utf-8">\nError\n\n\n
>
> ```
> Cannot
> POST /api/customer/savecustomer
> ```
>
> \n\n\n"}

POSTMAN:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44405

Why is it not found?

Comment: Have you checked if the .NET endpoint works with a tool like Postman? The error states that it can not find the API endpoint so it might has something to do with your routes.

Comment: Is the server running? Can you reach the endpoint using another tool like Postman? Is the port correct? Is the C# debug window showing any errors?

Comment: _"POSTMAN: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44405"_ - is there any particular reason why do you believe the server is on 44405 port?

Comment: In Postman this is working: http://localhost:5012/api/customer/savecustomer

Comment: did you see that's a whole different port?

Comment: Fix the port used by the Angular app.

Comment: Now i changed the service to the 5012 port and now i got some Cors Troubles.

Comment: [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I voted close because "need more details", but this should be closed as "typo". Everything you need to know is in the documentation. You should REALLY read that.

Comment: If you are using the ASP.NET Core Angular template then in dev it will be utilising the node proxy server to forward the calls. In this case you just need to make sure your proxy configuration is done properly in `proxy.conf.json`.